# SharePoint 2010 Architecture

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, architecture

If someone ask you in interview over phone

"Please explain SharePoint 2010 Architecture?"

What will be proper answer to this?

I understand that SharePoint 2010 consist of many architecture like Logical, Physical, Workflow, service application etc. But am I wrong?

Comment: The answer depends on the role. I would expect very different answers for that question from a business analyst and from a developer

Comment: I've converted this to Community Wiki. If it keeps getting flagged we may made need to close it because it is so vague.

Answer (score 2):

There is good article available in the slid share. Here's the link http://www.slideshare.net/sparked/sharepoint-2010-architecture-and-infrastructure.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2011/01/04/sharepoint-2010-architecture-slides-from-ignite-training.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the SharePoint 2010 Architecture is the defined well in the "SharePoint Wheel". One may think this is way too vague of terms, but SharePoint itself is such a robust and expansive platform, that it's hard to define it all without some vagueness.

[image]

For more in-depth explanation of each term: http://programmingshare-thienle.blogspot.com/2011/11/sharepoint-2010-wheel.html